# Make a http get request to rest api and convert to a collection

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to make a Meteor.http.get("localhost:4000/api/resource.json") and use the returned response as Meteor.collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Let's say the JSON looks like:

```
{
  'results': [
    {
      'name': 'bob',
      'eyes': 'brown'
    },
    {
      'name': 'sue',
      'eyes': 'blue'
    }
  ]
}
```

To insert that into a collection you would do:

```
Meteor.http.get("localhost:4000/api/resource.json", function(error, result) {
  if (result.statusCode === 200) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.results.length; i++) {
      MyCollection.insert(result.data.results[i])
    }
  }
  else {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can it be converted to a non persistent collection say if I want to retrieve a list posts from another site but don't want to save it in meteors mongo db but would like to interact with the data being returned (which is JSON) I.e use it in my views etc. right now I'm making that http call on the server inside a function which I call from the client but that data is never actually making it the client for some reson it's just dying on the sever. (I will post example shortly)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying you want to send the JSON to the client and have the client insert it into a local (unmanaged) collection. If that's what you want, then yes definitely: Meteor can do that. As for why your client isn't getting the data it's subscribed to, yes it would be helpful to see your code.

Comment: Note: Meteor function ends with );