# Most efficient method of pulling in weather data for multiple locations

Tags: meteor, weather-api

I'm working on a meteor mobile app that displays information about local places of interest and one of the things that I want to show is the weather in each location. I've currently got my locations stored with latlng coordinates and they're searchable by radius. I'd like to use the [openweathermap api](http://openweathermap.org/API#weather) to pull in some useful 'current conditions' information so that when a user looks at an entry they can see basic weather data. Ideally I'd like to limit the number of outgoing requests to keep the pages snappy (and API requests down)

I'm wondering if I can create a server collection of weather data that I update regularly, server-side (hourly?) that my clients then query (perhaps using a mongo $near lookup?) - that way all of my data is being handled within meteor, rather than each client going out to grab the latest data from the API. I don't want to have to iterate through all of the locations in my list and do a separate call out to the api for each as I have approx. 400 locations(!). I'm afraid I'm new to API requests (and meteor itself) so apologies if this is a poorly phrased question.

I'm not entirely sure if this is doable, or if it's even  the best approach - any advice (and links to any useful code snippets!) would be greatly appreciated!

## EDIT / UPDATE!

OK I haven't managed to get this working yet but I some more useful details on the data!
If I make a request to the openweather API I can get data back for all of their locations (which I would like to add/update to a collection). I could then do regular lookup, instead of making a client request straight out to them every time a user looks at a location. The JSON data looks like this:

`{
   "message":"accurate",
   "cod":"200",
   "count":50,
   "list":[
      {
         "id":2643076,
         "name":"Marazion",
         "coord":{
            "lon":-5.47505,
            "lat":50.125561
         },
         "main":{
            "temp":292.15,
            "pressure":1016,
            "humidity":68,
            "temp_min":292.15,
            "temp_max":292.15
         },
         "dt":1403707800,
         "wind":{
            "speed":8.7,
            "deg":110,
            "gust":13.9
         },
         "sys":{
            "country":""
         },
         "clouds":{
            "all":75
         },
         "weather":[
            {
               "id":721,
               "main":"Haze",
               "description":"haze",
               "icon":"50d"
            }
         ]
      }, ...`

Ideally I'd like to build my own local 'weather' collection that I can search using mongo's $near (to keep outbound requests down, and speed up), but I don't know if this will be possible because the format that the data comes back in - I think I'd need to structure my location data like this in order to use a geo search:

`"location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-5.47505,50.125561]
    }`

My questions are:

1. How can I build that collection (I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866363/make-a-http-get-request-to-rest-api-and-convert-to-a-collection) - could I do something similar and update existing entries in the collection on a regular basis?)
2. Does it just need to live on the server, or client too?
3. Do I need to manipulate the data in order to get a geo search to work?
4. *Is this even the right way to approach it??*

## EDIT/UPDATE2

Is this question too long/much? It feels like it. Maybe I should split it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes easily possible. Because your question is so large I'll give you a high level explanation of what I think you need to do.

You need to create a collection where you're gonna save the weather data in.
A request worker that requests new data and updates the collection on a set interval. Use something like [cron-tick](https://atmospherejs.com/package/cron-tick) for scheduling the interval.
Requesting data should only happen server side and I can recommend the [request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) npm package for that.

Meteor.publish the weather collection and have the client subscribe to that, with optionally a filter for it's location.

You should now be getting the weather data on your client and should be able to get freaky with it.